# Procedure Cache Dropping

Tags: sql-server, cache

We've experienced an issue with SQL Server dropping proc cache out of the blue.

I'm talking 4GB down to 0 in 2 minutes. This has occurred approx once per day in the last two weeks.

It does happens at random times and does not coincide with process.

Has anyone seen this before?

So far as I'm aware the cache its only wiped if `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` is executed or SQL is restarted.

> Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4226.00 (X64)   May 26 2009
>   14:58:11      Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation   Enterprise
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

```
32GB RAM
```

Any help much appreciated.

We use Idera SQL Diagnostic manager.

**Results:**

```
DateTime                Proc Cache Size MB 
23/12/2015 19:19:00     4,165.63 
23/12/2015 19:25:00     4,165.71 
23/12/2015 19:32:00     4,178.93 
23/12/2015 19:38:00     4,175.44 
23/12/2015 19:44:00     4,176.87 
23/12/2015 19:50:00     4,179.80 
23/12/2015 19:57:00     207.16 
23/12/2015 20:03:00     459.66 
23/12/2015 20:09:00     510.48 
23/12/2015 20:15:00     1,795.31 
23/12/2015 20:21:00     2,830.94 
23/12/2015 20:27:00     2,859.87 
23/12/2015 20:34:00     2,877.93 
23/12/2015 20:40:00     2,891.94 
23/12/2015 20:46:00     2,908.82 
23/12/2015 20:52:00     2,921.34 
23/12/2015 20:58:00     2,975.92
```

Comment: @Hpk Is there anything in the error log when that happens? Things like configuration options changed or freeproccache are logged

Comment: What is the max memory and RAM on the server ? The plans will get flushed out if there is memory pressure.

Comment: this isn't a virtual server is it? doesn't look like it based on version output. if it is virtual, check if balloon driver is reclaiming memory at this time.

Comment: Hi - nope its a physical server

Comment: Has anything changed on your box since this is a recent behavior?  For instance, is there a new application forcing SQL Server to surrender memory?  What monitoring tools do you have?

Comment: Is "Lock Pages in Memory" enabled?

Comment: Can you show us the message which says Cache is dropping ? Is this a NUMA system ?

Comment: I know this suggestion is a band aid until the root issue is identified but, set you minimum server memory from 0 to a level that will retain your buffer pool and minimize the performance issues you are having with the buffer pool rebuilding every time this happens.   If there is a non SQL Server application stealing your memory, the result of setting your min memory level could slow the startup of this application.

Comment: does buffer cache also drop at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

One reason could be somebody changing options or running sp_configure. That would be logged in your error log.

Please read this article: [Using Sp_configure To Change a Value Will Issue DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/using-spconfigure-change-value-will-issue-dbcc-freeproccache)

> using sp_configure to change a configuration value causes SQL Server
>   to issue a DBCC FREEPROCCACHE statement.

and

> The same behavior will occur if you use a GUI such as SQL Server
>   Enterprise Manager that issues an sp_configure call that changes a
>   parameter.

The [Plan Caching and Recompilation in SQL Server 2012 white paper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn148262.aspx) gives some other possibilities.

> **Flush Entire Plan Cache** The following operations flush the entire plan cache, and therefore, cause fresh compilations of batches that
>   are submitted the first time afterwards:
>
> - Detaching a database
> - Upgrading a database to a later database compatibility level
> - Restoring a database
> - `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` command
> - `RECONFIGURE` command (many of the options to this command cause a flush)
> - `ALTER DATABASE … MODIFY FILEGROUP` command
> - Modifying a collation using `ALTER DATABASE … COLLATE` command
>
> **Flush Database-Related Entries in Plan Cache** The following operations flush the plan cache entries that refer to a particular
>   database, and cause fresh compilations afterwards.
>
> - `DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB` command
> - `ALTER DATABASE … MODIFY NAME` = command
> - `ALTER DATABASE … SET ONLINE` command
> - `ALTER DATABASE … SET OFFLINE` command
> - `ALTER DATABASE … SET EMERGENCY` command
> - `DROP DATABASE` command
> - When a database auto-closes

Lots of these events should be in your log files.