# What could empty our cache (plan and buffer)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, monitoring, plan-cache, sp-blitzfirst

If I execute `sp_BlitzFirst` in my server, sometimes it tells me 2 things:

- Plan Cache Erased Recently (indeed my plan cache is around a few hundreds MBs)
- (sometimes) Page Life to low (indeed my page life expectancy is a few minutes and the buffer is down a few GBs instead of 40-50 most of the time)

Most of the time it's ok and the page life is around 2hour.

If I execute this:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260)
SELECT @path=path FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1

--Security Audit: Audit DBCC CHECKDB, DBCC CHECKTABLE, DBCC CHECKCATALOG,
--DBCC CHECKALLOC, DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP Events, and more.
SELECT TextData, Duration, StartTime, EndTime, SPID, ApplicationName, LoginName  
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass IN (116) AND (TextData like 'DBCC FREE%' OR TextData like 'DBCC FLUSH%')
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
```

I get nothing, so I guess this means no one executed any `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` or `DROPCLEANBUFFERS`. In case of memory pressure, SQL Server doesn't empty the cache (plan or buffer) but instead remove some items (with an algorithm of it's own), so I shouldn't see everything almost empty.

**So what could empty my cache?**

Trace with:

```
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 0, 6, N'%DBCC%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%ALTER DATABASE%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 1, 6, N'%sp_configure%'
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 0, 7, N'exec sp_reset_connection'
```

Didn't give anything, I don't have anything about `FLUSHPROCINDB` or `FREEPROCCACHE` or `FREESYSTEMCACHE` or `ALTER DATABASE` in my trace.

Perf Monitor of my cache we can see the drop occurring every 3-7min:

[image: Perf Monitor of my cache we can see the drop occurring every 3-7min]

No `sp_configure` after 2016-11-23 when I run this query:

[Link](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-when-were-the-sp_configure-options-last-changed/)

No flush in `sp_readerrorlog`. The server hasn't rebooted.

Comment: Changing [certain sp_configure](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124537/8783) options will cause plan flush.

Comment: Glen Berry lists some things that can cause the plan cache to be cleared, and notes that you should get a message about this in your error log.  Run sp_readerrorlog and search the results for "flush".  http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/eight-different-ways-to-clear-the-sql-server-plan-cache/

Comment: @JoeHayes the last message was 10hr ago  (which is weird but it doesn't match my problem)

Comment: Not really a duplicate but related: [Procedure Cache Dropping](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124487/procedure-cache-dropping/124537#124537)